# Where to Set Composer Environment Variables

Tags: php, composer-php

I don't want to disable `Xdebug`, I don't care that it's slower, so I see there is an environment variable `COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN` and the docs mention setting it in the config.

So, I opened my global `/Users/username/.composer/config.json` and add:

```
{
    "config": {
        "COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN": true
    }
}
```

No change.

Where or how do I set this environment variable to get rid of this damn message?

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4622

Answer (score 2):

The PHP CLI inherits the environment variables from your shell.  You can add the following line to your `.bash_profile` (or whatever you use for your shell).

`export COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN=1`

Make sure to close the terminal, and reopen it to load the new variable.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098263/58795

Answer (score 0):

Use `COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN` as ENVVAR https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4622#issuecomment-158678115

Answer (score 0):

Some installs (ubuntu, for one) setup php so that environment variables are not included as built-in `$_ENV` by default. Check that your `php.ini` includes "E" in the `variables_order` [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) setting.

In Ubuntu this is separated by cli and Apache paths. For command-line php you would maybe create a file in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-variables-order.ini` to override `php.ini` containing:

variables_order = "EGPCS"

Answer (score -1):

As per [Composer documentation for this flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-disable-xdebug-warn), ...

```
"COMPOSER_DISABLE_XDEBUG_WARN": 1
```

set it to `1`, not `true` to disable the warning.  (Ya, I know, if I was coding this part of Composer I would've accepted any truthy value but what can you do, ask for your money back?)

Comment: Nope. Set it to `1` and I still get the warning.