# How to see the development logs in termail of zend framework 2?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-studio

Iam familiar with ROR development. But recently started working in php zend framework. Is their a way to see the development logs live in the terminal(in linux) same as ROR as.

> RAILS_ENV=development
>
> rails s

But In Zend the its terminal command

> php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 public public/index

produce logs in production environment.How to get them  development like to monitor the code more specifically.
In documentation it has it like:

> if ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] == 'development') {
>        error_reporting(E_ALL);
>        ini_set("display_errors", 1);  }

But show error message in terminal as:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: APPLICATION_ENV in
>   /var/www/html/skeleton/public/index.php on line 7

that's bit wearied please suggest a way out thanks.

Comment: which version of zend framework you are using?

Comment: Difficult to to tell what you're asking here, but at a guess you're maybe looking for this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098006/setting-php-enviromental-variable-while-running-command-line-script

Comment: zend version 2.4.13

Comment: What you see in the terminal window are the web server logs (which will include errors). Zend Framework does not do any additional logging by default.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

The documentation assumes that you’re using Apache:

> Optionally, *when using Apache*, you can use the `APPLICATION_ENV` setting in your `VirtualHost` to let PHP output all its errors to the browser. This can be useful during the development of your application.

Source: [the manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#error-reporting).

## First solution: define `APPLICATION_ENV`

As discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098006/setting-php-enviromental-variable-while-running-command-line-script), you should be able to run your development server with defined `APPLICATION_ENV` using the following command:

```bash
APPLICATION_ENV=development php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 public public/index
```

## Second solution: use Apache

You may simply setup an Apache `VirtualHost` as said in [the manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server). Put the following in your `VirtualHost` config:

```apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And update your `hosts`:

```hosts
127.0.0.1 zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

Refer to [the manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server) in case of problems.

## Third solution: use [`zf-development-mode`](https://packagist.org/packages/zfcampus/zf-development-mode)

I won’t guide you through installation of [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/zfcampus/zf-development-mode) ([here are some instructions](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-development-mode#installation)), but I’ll present two solutions for checking (in your code) whether development mode is enabled.

### First method: check if `config/development.config.php` exists

After enabling development mode, contents of `config/development.config.php.dist` should be copied to `config/development.config.php`. In your code, use the following to check if you’re in development mode:

```
if (file_exists('config/development.config.php')) {
    // in default skeleton application. You may have to play with
    // __DIR__ if you’ve modified your public/index.php
}
```

### Second method: inject application config

Let’s assume that you want to check if development mode is enabled in a controller/service or other thing that can be created by a factory implementing `zend-servicemanager`’s `FactoryInterface`. Below I present example application config, factory and service:

#### `config/development.config.php.dist`

```
<?php

return [
    'development' => true
];
```

#### `Application\Service\Factory\ExampleServiceFactory`

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    return new ExampleService($container->get('Config'));
}
```

#### `Application\Service\ExampleService`

```
<?php

// imports, namespace…

class ExampleService
{
    protected $dev;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->dev = isset($config['development']) && $config['development'] === true;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        if ($this->dev) {
            // …
        }
    }
}
```