# Set global php environment variable from the command line?

Tags: php

I need to store an encryption key in an environment variable for a php application, but our security policy dictates that it cannot be defined from a file anywhere in the file system. Is there a way to set this variable from the command line or through some other method without relying on an env file?

Comment: It would still be in a file...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting PHP enviromental variable while running command line script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098006/setting-php-enviromental-variable-while-running-command-line-script)

Comment: what security team suggesting on env variable then ? cannot be from db as its env or cannot write using a file  . Ask if different type of files like .ini is alright and make those ini file not discover able

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables in an Apache config file and then access them in PHP.  If you want it to not be in a file, you can restart Apache after adding the environment variable to the file and then delete the Apache config file. You do not need it to be there while Apache has already been started. However, you cannot restart Apache without the config file if it crashes.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how you can not have it in a file.

in Apache config file (you must have mod_env enabled):

```
SetEnv NAME_OF_ENV_VAR put_your_encryption_key_here
```

In PHP:

```
$env_var = apache_getenv('NAME_OF_ENV_VAR');
```