# Environmental variables defined on the shell are not caught on Supervisord PHP Listener implementation

Tags: php, supervisord

I'v developed a supervidord listener implementation using PHP.

```
[eventlistener:listener]
numprocs=1
command=php /path_to_listener.php env=%(ENV_APP_ENV)s
events=TICK_60
user=apache
```

I want the task inside the listener is executed every 60 seconds in different environments. To do it I provide **env=%(ENV_APP_ENV)s** at the end of the listener.

I set the environment by (For example 'dev')
export APP_ENV=dev

After that, I reload **supervisord** and when I tail the listener the environment value is **localdev**. The new value **dev** is never changed.

How can I approach that? What I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you even set an environment variable that way? Have you tried setting it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098248/231316)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The **%(ENV_APP_ENV)s**  takes the value of the env variable **APP_ENV** when **supervisord** started running.